# Get clicked element html with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm listening for clicks of a number of element's. I want to show an alert when an user clicks on one, the alert's content should be the clicked element's innerHtml.

```
$(".tags-container > p").click(function (event) {
    alert('inner html');
    });
```

I could do it by adding the code to the html, but I prefer to use a jquery listener.

How can I show the element's innerHTML on the alert?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Do you want to which element was clicked? Your question: _How do I get the clicked inner html on click?_ is not clear.

Comment: If you get the inner HTML, either through jQuery's `html()` or JavaScript's `innerHTML` it will do just that, give you the HTML mark-up inside. If all you intent though is to get the text inside the `<p>` tag, ignoring any possible HTML mark-up inside it then you may be better of using jQuery's `text()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the HTML out of the `<p>` tag using jQuery's [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$(".tags-container > p").click(function(event) {
    alert($(this).html());
});​
```

Get the HTML out of the `<p>` tag using JavaScript's [**innerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML):

```
$(".tags-container > p").click(function(event) {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});​
```

Get just the text out of the `<p>` tag using jQuery's [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/), which will strip out any HTML and return the combined text.

```
$(".tags-container > p").click(function(event) {
    alert($(this).text());
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tags-container > p").click(function () {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Why not just use `this.innerHTML`?

Comment: jquery is jquery is jquery :)

Comment: @GungFoo: I'm all for using a standard approach but if there is no cross-browser issues with using innerHTML and the HTML value is what OP wants then why initialise an additional object to wrap around `this` only to call a method to obtain a value you already had available without the overhead?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery's `html()` function

```
$(".tags-container > p").click(function (event) {
    alert($(this).html());
    });
```

a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ukxvp/

Answer (score 0):

Like they said, just use $.html(). Personally, I'd just use innerHTML because $.html() filters out br elems and such; I'd just turn them into newlines.

```
$(".tags-container > p").click(function () {
   alert(this.innerHTML.replace(/<br>/, '\n'));
});
```

Comment: Why would you filter out html from the html that the OP, presumably, wants to alert and therefore show?